# Mongo return result only matched array row

Tags: mongodb, resultset

I currently have the following dataset (simplified):

```
{  
    'component_id':1,  
    '_locales':[   
        {  
            'url': 'dutch',  
            'locale': 'nl_NL'  
        },  
        {  
            'url': 'english',  
            'locale': 'en_US'  
        }  
    ]  
} (etc more rows similar to this but unique urls)
```

When I query for a specific url and locale I use the following query

```
db.find({'_locales': { '$elemMatch': { 'locale': 'nl_NL', 'url': 'dutch' } }});
```

I get the proper row back however '_locales' return the entire array including en_US which I don't need, is there anyway it only returns the matched array row, in this case:

```
'_locales':[   
{  
     'url': 'dutch',  
     'locale': 'nl_NL'  
}]
```

I have a feeling I have to iterate through the locales and match the row to the locale. It doesn't feel right, is there a better solution to do this (not iterating over the result set)? For example, changing the table structure? I was hoping to do it this way without making a second table for the locales only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always query for top level documents. Just because your query criteria involve matching a specific array element doesn't tell MongoDB that it should only return that element. Currently there's no way to return specific array elements other than using the $slice operator which is not what you need here.

There are feature requests in MongoDB JIRA that will allow for what you want but currently it is not possible.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. For now I'll iterate over the result as there are max 4 or 5 results in it so that would be a performance issue. Thank you.